# Why does Clang static analyzer think that this is use-after-free?

Tags: c, clang-static-analyzer, false-positive

I'm probably just stupid:

```
    fileref_t *fref;

    while (gli_filereflist != NULL)
    {
        fref = gli_filereflist;
        if (fref != NULL)
        {
            glk_fileref_destroy(fref);   <-------- Use of memory after it is freed
            fref = NULL;
        }
    }
```

This is after I added the NULL check and explicitly set fref to NULL after free().

Xcode 12.3. Original code [here](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/6747a2dae701a6abf646204ee8fa9cba0877cd77/glkimp/fileref.c#L340-L359).

If this is a false positive, is there a way to silence it?

EDIT: gli_filereflist is a linked list, which will point to the next item in the list when the first one is destroyed.

Comment: What's `gli_filereflist`?

Comment: It's an infinete loop that keeps calling `glk_fileref_destroy` on the same `gli_filereflist`. So of course the second iteration will try to destroy memory that is already destroyed. I guess you are missing code that changes `gli_filereflist` in the loop.

Comment: It is a [global pointer to a struct](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/6747a2dae701a6abf646204ee8fa9cba0877cd77/glkimp/fileref.c#L25-L26) (of type [fileref_t](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/6747a2dae701a6abf646204ee8fa9cba0877cd77/glkimp/glkimp.h#L342-L354))

Comment: You'd have to dig through the linked code to find it but `gli_filereflist` is a global that can be changed as the result of the `glk_fileref_destroy` call.

Comment: It is changed in [gli_delete_fileref ()](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/6747a2dae701a6abf646204ee8fa9cba0877cd77/glkimp/fileref.c#L82)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes - but does the compiler know that? If not, it would maybe optimize out the `fref = gli_filereflist` line.

Comment: That is, gli_filereflist is supposed to be a linked list, which will point to the next item in the list when the first one is destroyed. Why would the the compiler optimize out the `fref = gli_filereflist` line? How would I make it not?

Comment: @Petter OK, perhaps not the compiler, but the static analyzer won't know that the `gli_filereflist` is always changed, as that change is buried in a conditional, which itself depends on other conditionals. But the `fref = NULL;` is pointless, whatever else is happening.

Comment: Yeah, the `fref = NULL;`line was an attempt to silence the analyzer warning, as was the `if (fref != NULL)`line. Is there a way to do this that works? This is the only warning left, and it would be nice to get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried doing away with the `fref` entirely? Just a one-liner: `while (gli_filereflist != NULL) glk_fileref_destroy(gli_filereflist);`? Not sure if that's kosher, though.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea, but unfortunately it gives the same warning (now pointing at `glk_fileref_destroy(gli_filereflist);`)

Comment: I guess @adrian-mole 's explanation is the best answer I am going to get. I'm just expecting too much of the poor analyzer. I'll just have to rewrite the code in a completely different, more analyzer-friendly way. Feel free to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
    while (gli_filereflist)
    {
        fref = gli_filereflist;
        gli_filereflist = gli_filereflist->next;
        glk_fileref_destroy(fref);
    }
```